# Why does only internal microphone work on HP notebook?

Tags: linux, microphone, headset

I have tried many headsets and microphones, but they don't work on my notebook.

In addition, the speaker of headset works perfectly but the microphone not :(

How can I solve these problems? Thanks for your answers

Comment: What kind of headphones & microphones are you talking about, USB or 3.5mm pin ? Have you check audio & sound settings in your computer ? Which OS are you talking about ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like looks like Linux from the tag

Comment: In addition to what @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like asked, if it is a 3.5mm jack- is it two jacks or a combo jack (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/GzSEM.jpg for a combo jack example)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **`alsamixer`** and check if your input device is correctly set up. You might need to unmute and/or select your external Mic input first.

If that doesn't work, you might need to tell the driver its wiring (I am assuming an HDA compatible sound chip, which is more-or-less freely configurable). The sound driver needs to know how the pins of the chip are wired to the jacks (and controlling circuitry) on the mainboard. You can override this with the **`model`** parameter of the **`snd-hda-intel`** kernel module. The reason here might be that the Mic input works, but stays disabled because the driver doesn't recognize you plugging in your headset.

Also check the **`jackpoll_ms`** parameter.